# Concatenar conteúdo de um Array de Strings (JSON) gerando uma frase

Tags: javascript, json

Estou tentando unir o conteúdo de um array de strings em uma frase só, mas só consigo trazer o conteúdo todo separado por vírgulas. Detalhe, esse array vem de um arquivo *JSON* que é consumido por outro arquivo *JSON*.

A saída do meu código é:

```
  ["John","Peter","Sally","Jane"]
```

O que eu preciso:

```
John Peter Sally Jane
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Create JSON string from a JavaScript array.</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

var arr = [ "John", "Peter", "Sally", "Jane" ];
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(arr);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myJSON;

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Nesse caso, utilizei o método `JSON.stringify`, mas alguém sabe outro método que me possibilite fazer o que preciso?

Observação: Não utilizo nenhuma linguagem de programação, é um arquivo *JSON* que consome dados de outro, por isso não é possível simplesmente fazer um loop concatenando as strings do array. Usei *HTML* aqui só para exibir a saída do código.

Comment: Utilize o método [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) para  juntar todos os elementos de uma array ...  `var arr = [ "John", "Peter", "Sally", "Jane" ]; document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arr.join(' ');`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Acredito que você esteja procurando pelo método [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

O método `join` junta todos os elementos de um array em uma string e a retorna.

`join` aceita um parâmetro, que será o separador inserido entre as strings.

```js
// Aqui ao criar o array já é feito o join resultando em uma string
var jointedStr = [ "John", "Peter", "Sally", "Jane" ].join(' ');
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(jointedStr);

// Troquei innerHTML por innerText porque o alvo é texto e não a estrutura html.
document.getElementById("demo1").innerText = "String: " + jointedStr;
document.getElementById("demo2").innerText = "JSON: " + myJSON;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Create JSON string from a JavaScript array.</h2>

<p id="demo1"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Funcionou para mim, obrigada!